# Django-Creating User

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to create the inactive user and send them activation email. 
This is my view:

```
secret = hexlify(os.urandom(6))
userName = form.cleaned_data['email']
if User.objects.filter(username=userName):
    message = EmailMessage('portal/pay_email2.html',{'refid':pk, 'amount':total,'Payment':Payment,'secret': secret }, 'Madeeha ', to=[form.cleaned_data['email']])
    message.send()
else:
    userPass = hexlify(os.urandom(4))
    userMail = form.cleaned_data['email']
    user = User.objects.create_user(userName, userMail,userPass)
    user.save()
    message = EmailMessage('portal/pay_email.html',{'refid':pk, 'amount':total,'Payment':Payment,'userName':userName, 'userPass':userPass, 'secret': secret }, 'Madeeha ', to=[form.cleaned_data['email']])
    message.send()
```

Comment: i am creating user but it is creating active user and i want to create inactive user and send them mail for activation

Answer (score 3):

The User.objects.create_user method will create a user with the active flag set to true.

You have a couple of options:

- After the save you could set the value to be false, then update (extra database call)
- You could create the user using the longer manual notation (not using the helper method)
- Override the create_user method with a key-value for is_active=False:

  `# create_user(username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)`
  `User.objects.create_user('username', email='email', password='pass', is_active=False)`

Answer (score 1):

First you should share your User Model, too. If this is Django 1.5 , You can/should define a status field for users like `is_active`, `is_admin`,  `is_superuser` .(like `MattWritesCode` said).

Then you can simply create a user with a simple queryset:

```
create_user = UserProfile.objects.create_user(username=xxx, email=xx@xx.com, is_active=False,  is_admin=False)
```